Having to `mvn wrapper:wrapper` before Spring Maven project can successfully `docker compose up --build`
I am working with my repo (main branch): https://github.com/zephyrdark/SA58_AlvinLee_Fibonacci/tree/86645b82e747b1c074a6e4799d8b743f02c83e1c
I am attempting to prepare the repo such that anyone can easily clone it and run docker compose up --build to build and run it using Docker Desktop.
I tried fresh clones and even run docker system prune --all, docker image prune --all, and docker builder prune --all, before attempting docker compose up --build - it didn't build successfully.
However, after cloning to my local drive, if I run mvn wrapper:wrapper before docker compose up --build, it successfully builds and runs the docker container.
How do I configure my backend Dockerfile such that users can simply clone and run the docker compose up --build command, without them having to manually execute mvn wrapper:wrapper?

Steps to recreate error, followed by fix:

Clone repo to /your_directory

git clone git@github.com:zephyrdark/SA58_AlvinLee_Fibonacci.git


In the directory /your_directory/SA58_AlvinLee_Fibonacci, run:

docker compose up --build


It should attempt to build but fail with the below logs:

...
 => [backend final 2/6] RUN adduser     --disabled-password     --gecos ""     --home "/nonexistent"     --shell "/sbin/nologin"     --no-create-home     --uid "10001"     appuser                                            0.6s 
 => [backend deps 2/5] WORKDIR /build                                                                                                                                                                                          0.1s 
 => [backend deps 3/5] COPY --chmod=0755 mvnw mvnw                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => [backend deps 4/5] COPY .mvn/ .mvn/                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => ERROR [backend deps 5/5] RUN --mount=type=bind,source=pom.xml,target=pom.xml     --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 ./mvnw dependency:go-offline -DskipTests 


Now, change directory into /your_directory/SA58_AlvinLee_Fibonacci/backend-spring and run:

mvn wrapper:wrapper


Change directory back to /your_directory/SA58_AlvinLee_Fibonacci and run:

docker compose up --build


It should build successfully and run. You can test the frontend using http://localhost:3000 (which will call backend API via http://localhost:8080).



I am not sure of all the prerequisites, but you would at least need Docker Desktop, git, and mvn command.
This question is only about wanting to docker compose up --build. If you look at my repo, you will find github actions workflow as well - please ignore it.
I also found some online discussions mentioning that I should commit a maven-wrapper.jar ; I am not sure if this is related, but I do not see it neither before nor after running mvn wrapper:wrapper



I think you want multi-stage build. You can find example https://scalabledeveloper.com/posts/building-java-applications-using-maven-and-docker-multi-stage-builds/
